# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len(), Empty Variable?

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

I am trying to write a recursive function that will return the max value from a provided list. I have some code I'm trying to test and it's throwing the following error:

```
  line 10, in array_max
    if pos == len(num_list):
    TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I gather from some exploration that num_list = num_list.sort() is returning None. I don't know why though. Below is my current function:

```
def array_max(num_list, pos = 0):
    num_list = num_list.sort()

    if pos == len(num_list):
        return num_list[pos]

    counting = array_max(num_list, pos+1)
    return counting

l1 = [5,6,3,44,1,-5]
test = array_max(l1)
print(test)
```

To clarify, I am not looking for suggestions on the rest of the function. I'm just confused as to why I am getting this error. Thanks.

Comment: See https://realpython.com/python-sort/, specifically `sort() returns None and modifies the values in place`.

Comment: Why do you need the recursion if you already sorted the array and you know that last element will contain the max value?

Comment: @Black0ut Frankly, I'm just trying to figure out a way to get a recursive function to return the maximum value in a list. I'm not particular as to how I do that, so long as I can. This is probably not a very good way of doing it, but it's the way I thought of.

Comment: @kaya3 That is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The `list.sort()` function does not return a new list, but instead `None`; thus the `NoneType` error you get later. Instead, it sorts that specific instance of a list.

Basically you're storing the return value of the `.sort()` function (which is `None`) and later try to get the length of it with `len(num_list)` <=> `len(None)`

```
>>>a = [1, 4, 3, 2]
>>>a.sort()
>>>a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function however returns a new list.

```
>>>a = [1, 4, 3, 2]
>>>b = sorted(a)
>>>b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```